# jQuery Autocomplete plugin - How to dynamically update data list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) for a smart input box. I want the first parameter in the input box to be autocompleted from one dataset, then once that has been selected change the dataset for the second parameter.

So if I have the following:

```
    var foo = ['a','b','c'];
    var bar = ['x','y','z'];

    $("#input_box").autocomplete(
        foo, { multiple: true, multipleSeparator: " "}
            );
```

I want to be able to dynamically change the 'foo' dataset to 'bar' after the first parameter has been autocompleted.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var fubar = foo;
$("#input_box").autocomplete(
        fubar, { multiple: true, multipleSeparator: " "}
            ).live('keyup', function() {
               if($(this).val().length > 1)
                      fubar = bar;
               else   fubar = foo;
});
```

//EDITED, forgot .length which is key :)